# Golden Gate Replication - Postgres Instances

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, oracle-golden-gate

Can golden gate be used for bidirectional replication of 2 postgres (RDS or Aurora) db instances in AWS?

Comment: Brief update to this post, the GoldenGate product recently added Source / Capture / Extract capabilities for PostgreSQL (including support for Amazon AWS Aurora and RDS) More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/19.1/gghdb/understanding-whats-supported-postgresql.html#GUID-7F290F2D-40D3-410D-9D29-F3E58802878E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it, can't. PostgreSQL can be only the target of Oracle GoldenGate replication. It can not be the source database.

You can replicate from an another vendor (like Oracle, MS SQL, Sybase, DB2) to a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Thanks @Adam. Are there any other tools which can be used for cross-data center replication of RDS / Aurora postgres instances?

Comment: PosgreSQL 10 has introduced its own logical database replication. This might be what you are looking for. Look here for more details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html